# Read file into array and return it from a function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, lua

In Lua, I have such a function to read a file into an array:

```
function readFile(file)
  local output = {}
  local f = io.open(file)
  for each in f:lines() do
    output[#output+1] = each
  end
  f:close()
  return output
end
```

Now in C++, I tried to write that like this:

```
string * readFile(file) {
  string line;
  static string output[] = {};
  ifstream stream(file);
  while(getline(stream, line)) {
    output[sizeof(output)+1] = line;
  }
  stream.close();
  return output;
}
```

I know you can't return arrays from functions, only pointers. So I did this:

```
string *lines = readFile("stuff.txt");
```

And it threw me the error `cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>} to' std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' in intialization string *lines = readFile("stuff.txt");`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here, and is there a better way to read files into arrays?

**EDIT:**
I'm going to be using the returned array to do value matching using a for loop. In Lua this would be written as:

```
for _, each in ipairs(output) do
  if each == (some condition here) then
    --Do Something
  end
end
```

How can this be done in C++, using vectors (according to the answer by Jerry Coffin)?

**EDIT 2:**
I can't match the vectors correctly for some reason. I wrote the code in a separate test file.

```
int main() {
  vector<string> stuff = read_pass();
  cout << stuff.size() << endl;
  cout << stuff[0] << endl;
  if (stuff[0] == "admin") { 
    cout << "true"; 
  }
  else { 
    cout << "false"; 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`read_pass()` looks like this:

```
vector<string> read_pass() {
  ifstream stream("stuff.txt");
  string line;
  vector<string> lines;
  while(getline(stream, line)) {
    lines.push_back(line);
  }
  stream.close();
  return lines;
}
```

And `stuff.txt` looks like this:

```
admin
why?
ksfndj
```

I just put it some random lines to test the code. Every time I compile and run main.cpp the output I get is

```
3
admin
false
```

So why isn't the code being matched properly?

**EDIT 3:**

So instead of forcing myself down the vectors method of doing things, I decided to try this instead:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "basefunc.h"

using namespace std;

int main() { 
  string storedUsrnm;
  string storedPw;
  string pw = "admin";
  string usrnm = "admin";
  ifstream usernames("usrnm.accts");
  ifstream passwords("usrpw.accts");
  while(getline(usernames, storedUsrnm)) {
    getline(passwords, storedPw);
    print("StoredUsrnm " + storedUsrnm);
    print("StoredPw: " + storedPw);
    if (storedUsrnm == usrnm && storedPw == pw) {
      print("True!");
      return 0;
    }
  }
  print("False!");
  return 0;
}
```

Where print() is

```
void print(string str) {
  cout << str << endl;
}
```

This still prints false, at the end, and it leads me to believe that for some reason, the `"admin"` read by the ifstream is different from the `"admin"` string. Any explanations for how this is so? Or does this code not work either?

Comment: `output` does not automatically resize itself. What you're doing here `output[sizeof(output)+1]` is undefined.

Comment: And even if you could resize an array like that, the `sizeof` operator will yield the number of bytes in the array, not the number of entries, so that addressing would be wrong.

Comment: Also, returning pointers to arrays allocated on the stack is a bad idea, as explained [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091003102624AAbmStp).

Comment: @LeeYi your code works fine for me, make sure you have no spaces in your input file and that it was creating on the same OS as your compiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I finally came up with the answer

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef map<int, string> strArr;

strArr readFile(string file) {
  ifstream stream(file);
  string line;
  strArr output;
  while(getline(stream, line)) {
    output[output.size()+1] = line;
  }
  stream.close();
  return output;
}
```

It doesn't read the file into an array, but it does return a map that does basically the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look to me like your current code should even compile. Anyway, I'd probably do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> read_file(std::istream &infile) { 

    std:string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
        lines.push_back(line);

    return lines;
}
```

So the basic idea here is to read a line from the file, and if that succeeded, add that line (with `push_back`) to the vector of results. Repeat until reading a line from the file fails. Then return the vector of all the lines to the caller.

A few notes: especially at first, it's fairly safe to presume that any use of pointers is probably a mistake. That shouldn't be taken as an indication that pointers are terribly difficult to work with, or anything like that--just that they're almost never necessary for the kinds of things most relative beginners do in C++.

Likewise with arrays--at first, assume that what you might think of as an array in some other language translates to a `std::vector` in C++. C++ does also have arrays, but using them can wait a while (a long while, IMO--I've been writing C++ for decades now, and virtually never use raw pointers *or* arrays at all).

In the interest of simplicity, I've consolidated the data into the program, so it reads the data from the stringstream, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> read_pass(istream &is) {
    string line;
    vector<string> lines;
    while (getline(is, line)) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    return lines;
}

int main() {
    istringstream input{ "admin\nwhy?\nksfndj" };
    // To read from an external file, change the preceding line to:
    // ifstream input{ "stuff.txt" };

    vector<string> stuff = read_pass(input);
    cout << stuff.size() << endl;
    cout << stuff[0] << endl;
    if (stuff[0] == "admin") {
        cout << "true";
    }
    else {
        cout << "false";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At least for me, this produces:

```
3
admin
true
```

...indicating that it has worked as expected. I get the same with an external file. If you're not getting the same with an external file, my immediate guess would be that (at least the first line of) the file contains some data you're not expecting. If the problem continues, you might consider writing out the individual characters of the strings you read in numeric format, to give a more explicit idea of what you're really reading.

Comment: So can I use this like an array? Also, how to I pass arguments to this function?

Comment: @LeeYi: yes, mostly--that is, you can certainly index into it like an array. Unlike an array, you can get its size with `lines.size()`, add new items to it with `.push_back()`, delete things with `.erase()`, etc.

Comment: I have got the vectors working now, but how do I match a certain value? For example, `if (lines[0] == "hi")`

Comment: @LeeYi: `if (lines[0] == "hi")` will work (assuming `lines` is a vector of `std::string`, as suggested).

Comment: @LeeYi: I've added a complete demo program.

Comment: With one line in the input file, it works perfectly fine, but with more than one line it doesn't work. Does the stream you input into the function have to be an `istringstream`?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the example where you used the external file?

Comment: @LeeYi: I've added a comment pointing to the one change needed to get it to read from an external file.

Comment: It can read from an `istringstream`, but for some reason it just doesn't work with an external file